# $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ define as $f(x,y)=x^2 e^y+ |x-y|$ - Partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ define as $f(x,y)=x^2 e^y+ |x-y|$. A part of this problem as to determine which points of the function possess a partial derivative.

The solution tell  that $f$ has partial derivative except when $x=y$, and the partial derivatives are $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)= 2xy + sgn(x-y)$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)= x^2e^y + sgn(x-y)$$

Is anyone could take time to explain to me what is the function $sgn()$ and how to obtain it from the main function?

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

$sgn$ is just the sign function.

$sgn(x)=-1$ if $x<0$

$sgn(x)=0$ if $x=0$

$sgn(x)=1$ if $x>0$

So in your case, it would be $sgn(x-y)=-1$ if $x-y<0$ which makes sense because you are taking the derivative of the absolute value.

Also, your second derivative should be $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It must be $\;f'_x(x,y)=2xe^y+sgn(x-y)\;$ . The function sgn is the sign function:

$$sgn(x)=\begin{cases}\;\;\,1,\,&x>0\\{}\\\;\,\;0,\,&x=0\\{}\\-1,\,&x<0\end{cases}$$

Thus, if for example $\;x-y<0\;$ , then $\;|x-y|=y-x\;$ , so

$$f'_x(x,y)=2xe^y+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y-x)=2xe^y-1=2xe^y+sgn(x-y)$$

and likewise for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hints

1. Look up "sgn function" at google.
2. Since $x^2e^y$ has partial derivatives everywhere, the question is really about the points where $|x-y|$ has partial derivatives.